# Function of an object not being called when being called inside another function of that object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am still working on a timer and I'm rebuilding my code, so that the timer is an object, and so that I can have multiple. This is what I did so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        a = new Timer("#timerText");
        a.set(9, 12);
    });

function Timer (element) {

var minutes, seconds, finalTimeInSeconds, displayMinutes, displaySeconds;

    this.set = function(inputMins, inputSecs) {
        alert("working!");
        minutes = inputMinutes; 
        seconds = inputSeconds; 
        finalTimeInSeconds = minutes*60 + seconds; //finalTimeInSeconds is the time it takes for the timer to be 00:00 in seconds.
        this.print();
    }

    this.print = function() {
        alert("printin!");
        displayMinutes = (minutes.toString().length == 2) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;    //ternary operator: adds a zero to the beggining 
        displaySeconds = (seconds.toString().length == 2) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;    //of the number if it has only one caracter.
        $(element).text(displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds);
    }

}
```

But the `print` function doesn't work when I call it via the `set` function. Why?

Thanks to anyone that answers!

Comment: any developer tools console errors?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What does it do, what doesn't it do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ffz1w00x/

Comment: This was a very naive question, but I'm glad I made it, because now I know about the console :-)

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, i fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the argument names — you're not using the names you've defined:

```
this.set = function(inputMins, inputSecs) {
    alert("working!");
    minutes = inputMins; // fix here
    seconds = inputSecs;  // fix here
    finalTimeInSeconds = minutes*60 + seconds; //finalTimeInSeconds is the time it takes for the timer to be 00:00 in seconds.
    this.print();
}
```

You must to learn to use the console. The error throws inmediately

Comment: Of course, sorry for the ingenuity but I'm starting out. I'll be checking the console from now on.